# JavaFx: Bind element's index in a list to a property of the element

Tags: java, javafx, binding, javafx-8

I have an `ObservableList<Model>` where the model has an `IntegerProperty` and I want to bind the position(index) of that element in the lost to this `IntegerProperty`. So if I move the element in that list, I want also to change the property.

I have found a similar question, but I don't know why is its answer accepted, when the answer is nothing to do with the question...
I am talking about this: [How to bind the position in a List to an attribute of that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217814/how-to-bind-the-position-in-a-list-to-an-attribute-of-that-element)

I don't have to do anything with selected item, simply just to bind to its property the indexOf in list.

I tried this why but it doesn't updates id I move the elemnt in the list:

```
item.indexProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> observableList.indexOf(item), observableList));
```

If you have any other suggestion without using a ListChangeListener I would appreciate it.

Comment: I find it odd that `Bindings.createIntegerBinding(...)` isn't working for you. I just tried the same thing and the `IntegerProperty` was updated properly. Though the options provided by _fabian_ are going to be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListChangeListener` is a good way of doing this since it only requires using a single listener.

```
public static class Item {

    private final IntegerProperty index = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(index.get());
    }

}
```

```
ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
items.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
    boolean hadNext;
    while ((hadNext = c.next()) && c.wasPermutated()) {
        int to = c.getTo();
        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < to; i++) {
            items.get(i).index.set(i);
        }
    }

    while (hadNext) {
        if (c.wasReplaced()) {
            int to = c.getTo();
            for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < to; i++) {
                items.get(i).index.set(i);
            }
        } else {
            if (!c.wasUpdated()) {
                // add/remove change
                int to = items.size();
                for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < to; i++) {
                    items.get(i).index.set(i);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        hadNext = c.next();
    }

});
```

---

Alternatively you could use `FXCollections.observableList` and let the backing list deal with this:

```
private static class ItemsList extends AbstractList<Item> {

    private final List<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Item get(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return data.size();
    }

    private void updateFromIndex(int index) {
        int size = size();

        for (; index < size; index++) {
            data.get(index).index.set(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Item remove(int index) {
        Item result = data.remove(index);
        updateFromIndex(index);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Item element) {
        data.add(index, element);
        updateFromIndex(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Item set(int index, Item element) {
        element.index.set(index);
        return data.set(index, element);
    }

}
```

```
ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableList(new ItemsList());
```

Note that there are optimisations for handling operations doing multiple insertions/deletions that could be done for the backing list.

---

In both cases

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(items);
    items.add(new Item());
}
System.out.println(items);
Collections.swap(items, 0, 4);
System.out.println(items);
Collections.swap(items, 2, 3);
System.out.println(items);
Collections.swap(items, 0, 2);
System.out.println(items);
```

yields the following console printout:

```
[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: So would you recommend the `ListChangeListener` solution?

Comment: Yes. Or is there any reason not to use this approach? This way you can be sure to update every item twice at most (once for permutations, once for add/replace)...

Comment: No, or not an important reason, I just thought there is a simple more readable solution than the listener approach.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to update all properties on every change with   `items.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Model> c) -> {
   int i=0;
   for (Model model : c.getList()) {
    model.setIndex(i++);
   }
  });`

Comment: @c0der It would be possible, but you may do more work than neccessary. e.g. consider replacing a single element or adding/removing from the end of the list...

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is what I thought. Maybe less efficient but more concise code. I'll post it as another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

"A simple more readable solution" could be

```
items.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Model> c) -> {
    int i=0;
    for (Model model : c.getList()) {
        model.setIndex(i++);
    }
})
```

It initializes all properties on first `add` and keeps all properties updated. 
Note fabian's comment:

> you may do more work than necessary

.